# pass multiple fields to django rest framework api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My model

```
class car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    speed = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My api serializer

```
class carSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = car
        fields = ('name', 'speed', 'age')
```

My list view

```
class carListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = carSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('name', 'speed', 'age')
```

How can I search the model fields `name`, `speed`, `age` via the api link?

Currently, I am able to search a single field using

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?name=Toyoto
```

How can I modify the above link to search multiple fields ?
How can I modify the above link to search partial letters rather than exact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass all `params` like below

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?name=Toyoto&speed=90&age=55
```

## using python "requests" package

```
import requests


params = {'name': 'Toyoto', 'speed': '90', 'age': '95'}
url  = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
r = requests.get(url, params)
print(r.json())
```

## for search like "icontains" you can use `filterset_class` like below

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from .models import car


class CarFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name="name", lookup_expr='icontains')
    speed = filters.CharFilter(field_name="speed", lookup_expr='icontains')
    age = filters.CharFilter(field_name="age", lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = car
        fields = ('name', 'speed', 'age')

class carListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = carSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = CarFilter
```

Comment: how can I change it to accept partial names and not sensitive to cap instead of full and exact as in, http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?name=to